# Instant search with Whoosh - Index and search a MySQL table using Whoosh outputing JSON results

Tags: python, mysql, json, search, whoosh

I want to index a MySQL table using Whoosh and create an instant search page, so I need the results of the Whoosh search to be in JSON. Is there a script or a project that implements this already? I've tried searching but I only find Haystack search for Django.

If not can I get some broad pointers how I should go about doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Whoosh [Results](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/api/searching.html#whoosh.searching.Results) object is basically a list of dictionaries. From the [examples](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/searching.html):

```
>>> # Show the best hit's stored fields
>>> results[0]
{"title": u"Hello World in Python", "path": u"/a/b/c"}
>>> results[0:2]
[{"title": u"Hello World in Python", "path": u"/a/b/c"}, {"title": u"Foo", "path": u"/bar"}]
```

You could very easily turn this into JSON:

```
import json
def results2json(results):
   return json.dumps([r for r in results])
```